# How can I add locations as well as their descriptions to "My Map" on google maps with the api?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to create a php form that takes in the location, description, etc and then uses the google maps API to add it to a "my map" on my google account.

I'm totally lost in how to even begin doing this though so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, the Google Maps API dos not support the My Maps feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Google Maps Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/) - you can operate using that API with all of your maps. :)